# Is there any custom date picker for iOS where year selection is optional?

Tags: ios, uipickerview, uidatepicker

I need to be able to select day and month and leave the option to the user to select the year or not. For example I was thinking a list with all the years and at the end an added option "no selection".

Any ideas how to do that?

I suppose that using the picker view is one solution but not sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using xamarin.ios what I did was create a toolbar on top of the thumbwheel with a Done and a Cancel buttons. When you click done the value is set, and you click cancel what you need to do is set the Datepicker value to a value like 1900-1-1 and change the uitextfield value to something like "Not set".

I'm using xamarin forms. This is what I have in my custom renderer:

```
public override void Draw (CGRect rect)
{
    base.Draw (rect);
    DatePicker elem = (DatePicker)Element;
    UITextField textField = (UITextField)Control;

    var toolbar = new UIToolbar(new CGRect(0.0f, 0.0f, Control.Frame.Size.Width, 44.0f));

    toolbar.Items = new[]
    {
        new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Cancel,(object sender, EventArgs e) => {
            if (elem.SetValueNullAction!=null){
                elem.SetValueNullAction();
                textField.Text = DefaultNotSetText;
            }
        }),
        new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace),
        new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done,(object sender, EventArgs e) => {
            elem.Unfocus();
        })
    };

    textField.InputAccessoryView = toolbar;
    textField.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
    textField.TextColor = Color.FromHex ("999999").ToUIColor ();
    CGRect frame = textField.Frame;
    frame.Width = 100;
    textField.Frame = frame;
    if (elem.Date == elem.MinimumDate) {
        textField.Text = ((DatePicker)this.Element).Label;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try of [CKPickerView](https://github.com/cybertk/CKPickerView), it allows very easy customization on `UIDatePicker`.

[image: snapshot]